# Lower bound of $x$ such that $x^{-t}\log x \le A, t\in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

$t, A$ are constants and $t \in (0, 1)$.

How to give a lower bound $x_0$ in terms of $t, A$ such that for all $x > x_0$, $x^{-t}\log x \le A$?

Answer (score 1):

At some point, you will need to solve the equation
$$x^{-t}\log(x)=A$$ that is to say
$$ x^{-t}\log(x^{-t})=- A t\implies x_*=\left(-\frac{W(-A t)}{A t}\right)^{\frac{1}{t}}$$ where appears Lambert function.

On the other side, the derivative of
$$f(x)=x^{-t}\log(x)-A \implies f'(x)=x^{-(t+1)} (1-t \log (x))$$ is decreasing as long as $t \log(x) > 1$.

Combine the above to check if $x_*$ is an upper or lower bound for the inequality.